# Why are the colors changing with MATLAB contourf in a loop?

Tags: matlab, loops, video, colors

I have a matlab program which is supposed to describe a certain diffusion phenomenon. I made a video with a loop, but it seems to me that the scale of the  colors is changing at each iteration :

Here is partly the code (it's pretty long so I think it's better to write only the relevent part, tell me if I should copy everything and with the functions):

```
...
w = VideoWriter('video_lin.avi');
MovDC(maxt) = struct('cdata',[],'colormap',[]);
...

for k=1:maxt
...
 contourf(f);
 colormap('hot')
 MovDC(:,k) = getframe;

end

 open(w)
 writeVideo(w,MovDC)
 close(w)
```

It looks like when I write `colormap('hot')` the program invent a new scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to keep your color range constant:

```
contourf(f);
caxis([0 1]); % replace the range [0 1] with one that fits your data in f
```

Colors are changing because `contourf` automatically scales the colormap to enhance color constrast (this is like `imagesc` behaviour vs. `image`). In other words, by default the whole colormap is applied to the range `[min(f) max(f)]`, which may change for each frame in your example. To avoid this behaviour, just fix the range by using `caxis`.

Two more tips:

- the line `colormap('hot')` can be safely moved before the beginning of the `for` loop
- showing the `colorbar` (which also shows you the values in `f` associated with the colormap) can help you understanding the "color-changing" problem discussed above.